# Logstash service on linux continuously polls conf.d folder

Tags: linux, postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash

**My task**: to run Logstash service on Linux to read config files in `conf.d` folder and send data from PostgreSQL to Elasticsearch.

**Problem**: after starting the Logstash service it polls continuously the folder, so repeated data can be passed to Elasticsearch. Even if I use specified field as primary key the store.size of the related index in Elasticsearch grows.

Before:

> green open curentstates             OBXrU9kGRoaad8Pxsffz0g 1 1 101 149  **42.1kb** 41.9kb

After few minutes:

> green open curentstates             OBXrU9kGRoaad8Pxsffz0g 1 1 101 444  **1.4mb** 741.8kb

I tried to find polling interval in Logstash config files but with no results.

Here is a sample of my .conf file stored in `conf.d` folder:

```
input {
jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://myhost:5432/postgres"
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => "postgres"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/driver/postgresql-42.2.11.jre7.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT * from CURENTST"
}}
output {
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "myhost:9200"
    index => "fias"
    document_type => "curentst"
    document_id => "%{curentstid}"
}}
```

Comment: Can you see a file called .logstash_jdbc_last_run getting created in the conf.d folder after logstash fetched records from the database? If yes, post the value/content of that file.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are only config files that I put before. I can see that data is loaded in Elasticsearch via Kibana

Comment: Then please add the setting last_run_metadata_path to your input plugin. The value should be the *absolute* path to your conf.d folder and pointing to a file called .logstash_jdbc_last_run. For example: `last_run_metadata_path => "/home/logstash/conf.d/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"` (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html for reference). Try this and let me know if there was a difference.

Comment: You dont need to create that file by your own. Logstash will automatically create it on pipeline startup.

Comment: did my suggestion work?